# Convert Shapes item into UIElement

Tags: c#, .net

I need help with converting a Shapes item into an UIElement in C#

```cs
Children.Insert(newPosition, SelectedShape);
```

I want to insert a shape into a children list at a particular position.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Web? Please add relevant tag

Comment: My frame work is UWP